# Python subprocess to execute remote server commands

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell, subprocess

I have to execute  python script that reside in remote machine and I am using below script:

```
from subprocess import call
ip = 1.1.1.1
call(["ssh", ip, "\"cd scripts; python -u get_details.py --web_server\""])
```

getting below error:

```
bash: cd scripts; python -u get_details.py --web_server: command not found
```

running in bash command line directly :

```
 ssh 1.1.1.1 "cd scripts; python -u get_details.py --web_server"
```

Asking below input and returning output

```
 1. USA
 2. UK
 Choose input: 1

 www.cisco_us.com is up
```

Please let me how fix or any other better way to achive this in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to drop the quotation marks because the shell removes them.  This:

```
ssh 1.1.1.1 "cd scripts; python -u get_details.py --web_server"
```

is equivalent to:

```
call(["ssh", ip, "cd scripts; python -u get_details.py --web_server"])
```

If you use `call` this way, there is no shell involved on the client side (which is a good thing), only on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

A way to make sure that your arguments are always prepared correctly is to use python's [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) module. You can do the following:

```py
import shlex
import subprocess

ip = '1.1.1.1'
cmd = "ssh {} 'cd scripts; python -u get_details.py --web_server'".format(ip)

subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

It ensures your arguments are correctly prepared.

---

I'd also recommend you to have a look at [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/). It's a python's library that helps you managing SSH connections.

Comment: which is best method and reliable ? Paramiko or configure ssh passwordless and use subprocess

Comment: I would recommend Paramiko. You have more control, and it's probably more secure.

Comment: Ok Let me try it